# WEBAUTHN how can we detect that device is registered before to give to client side login or register page dynamically

Tags: webauthn, fido, yubico

I want to load login or register page for webauthn dynamically but I can not detect the device is registered before or not. is there any solution or advice for this?

If Client side decide to which page will using I can do but ı can not manage loading of action type via server side